# Changing the value of a Javascript controlled HTML form and encoding the input and passing through to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, variables, encoding

i'm relatively new to PHP and I would think this would be a simple code to manage. What i want to do is have an input box in HTML on a page, and when someone enters a name in to there, with Javascript i want to be able to output in the same input box an encoded version of the name with a website string in front of it creating a new link. Now when someone accesses this link in their web browser, it shows the name variable on the page.

**Example**

John enters his name in to the HTML form.

> "John Dickinson"

When he presses the submit button, the HTML input box he just entered his name in to changes to something like:

> "http://www.example.com/johndickinsonencoded/"

where Johndickinsonencoded is an encoded string of his name.

When "http://www.example.com/johndickinsonencoded/" is accessed in a web browser, it outputs on the screen:

> "Hello John Dickinson"

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Zilch; if i wanted to pay, i would've went straight to a web dev to get it done, however I do want to learn, and this shouldn't be a hard task. I've already got it outputting a url in the form through javascript, all i really need to know is the encoding part. I just put up the whole scenario to explain it a bit better. PHP side of things, it already reads the url variables and outputs it correctly, all i want to do is encode it now so the variable can't be directly readable to any Tom, Dick or Harry.

Comment: you need to read about apache mod_rewerite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need some way of encoding the field using JavaScript and decoding the string when it gets to PHP. Choosing an codec that goes forwards and backwards should be fairly easy, even just using base64  should do it. (JavaScript doesn't have built-in support for base64 encoding, but there are numerous examples of such around.) If you have some other means of encoding and decoding the field, that's fine, too.

On the server side, you are going to have to do some rewriting using [Apache mod_rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Basically, you'll want something like this either in the  section of httpd.conf, or a local .htaccess file:

```
# use mod_rewrite to enable passing encoded user name as a "Clean URL"
RewriteEngine On
# Define the rewrite base -- / says use what is immediately after the hostname part
RewriteBase /
# Send bare requests to index.php
RewriteRule ^$  index.php [L]
# Don't rewrite requests for files, directories, or symlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# Send requests to index.php, appending the portion following the RewriteBase
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?n=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The last will rewrite your original url: "http://www.example.com/johnsmithencoded" to "http://www.example.com/index.php?n=johnsmithencoded", from there, you can get the query parameter via $_GET['n'] and decode it as needed.